# How to remove unused languages from Localizable.xcstrings

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, ios17

I created the file and added a language that I don't want to translate in my app, how can I delete the language and keep only the others that I want?

[image: unused]

In the image, for example, I wanted to keep only `English` and `Portuguese`, and delete `Danish` and `Swedish`.

PS1: I cannot remove by pressing `delete` on keyboard

PS2: There are no references to the language in source of the file, only the default language (`English`) and the translation in this case (`Portuguese`)

[image: source]

How the delete the unused languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on Known Regions in your project settings. You should remove there.

[image]

Comment: It's not there either.

Comment: @Nickkk definetly there. You can try to figure it out by adding one language and checking git changes.

Comment: There are no git changes for the project file (but there are changes for the .xcstrings file). This occurred after importing the translations. I then had translations in the 3 languages Portuguese, Portuguese (Portugal) and Portuguese (Brazil), but in the project settings I only had listed Portuguese (Brazil) and Portuguese (Portugal), which were the ones before the import. This was probably caused by the imported files having different locale identifiers than the exported ones, e.g. `PT` instead of `PT-PT`, (the translator's software apparently changed it).

Comment: @Nickkk Try clean new repo without .gitignore file and any localizations. Then you will see right diffs.

Comment: I finally figured out that this only happens when importing localizations from a .xliff file which doesn't contain translations for storyboard files. My project doesn't contain storyboards but creates the UI programmatically. When importing localizations from storyboard files and source code files in a clean project, the language is correctly added to the project settings. I filed a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem- did a grep with the language code in the root of the git workspace and got a match in the `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` file. Deleted this (it'll get automatically re-created) and the language was removed. I made sure to quit Xcode while deleting the file.

This file is in the `ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/{user}.xcuserdatad` directory. Since most people have `xcuserdata` in gitignore, that explains why it doesn't show up as modified.